# Replace tablespoon/s and teaspoon/s

Tags: regex, character-replacement

I'm using BBEdit or Visual Code and I'm not too experienced with regex but would like to do a simple find and replace to all instances of "teaspoon(s)" (as in teaspoon or teaspoon***s***) and "tablespoon(s)" with "tsp" and "tbsp".

replace:

```
 1 tablespoon sugar
 2 teaspoons salt
 2 tablespoons butter
 3 teaspoons crystal meth
```

with:

```
1 tbsp sugar
2 tsp salt
2 tbsp butter
3 tsp crystal meth
```

The replace search term should encompass all four variants in one go. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the "b" from "table" to do it in one replacement:

search: `\bt(?:a(b)le|ea)spoons?\b`
replace: `t$1sp`

`$1` is a placeholder for the captured content (the `b` if any).

Comment: this works brilliantly and I think understand the search code. Thank you!

Comment: @Myslnik: Thanks, as you can see, there's nothing incredible here.